# How to grouping postgresql when id is same into new add value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table like this:

[image]

And I would like to bring value item in one row when `user_input_id` and `question_id` is duplicate.

The result that I wish is this:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to querying it?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do taht with string_agg(value,',') in postgresql.

```
select user_input_id,question_id,        
string_agg(value,',') as other_names
from table_name
group by  user_input_id,question_id
order by user_input_id,question_id
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can also have array_aggr() in postgres:

```
select user_input_id,question_id,        
array_agg(value::text ) as other_names
from table_name
group by  user_input_id,question_id
order by user_input_id,question_id
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Akhmad Ali wants a comma separated list, so `string_agg(value, ',')` seems a better fit

Answer (score 0):

Just fill a temp table with data of this table and truncate it. Then use aggregate functions like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_tbl(
   columns ...
);    
insert into temp_tbl
select * from main_tbl

truncate table main_tbl

insert into main_tbl


select user_input_id,question_id, string_agg(value, ',')
from temp_tbl 
group by user_input_id,question_id
```